# Valgrind reporting lost bytes even after using free()

Tags: c, valgrind, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have been trying a few things in C language after reading about memory allocation. Everything seemed to have been pretty soft and eye-catching, until I got stuck in this program. It works as intended but valgrind clearly states a whole different story. Here's my program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NSTRINGS 3

int main()
{
    char **v = NULL;
    int sum = 0;
    char str[80]={'\0'};
    int i = 0, pos = 0;
    v = (char**) calloc((NSTRINGS * sizeof(char*)),1);

    while(1)
    {
        for(i = 0; i < NSTRINGS; i++)
        {
            printf("[%d] ", i+1);
            if(v[i] == NULL)
                printf("(Empty)\n");
            else
                printf("%s\n", v[i]);
        }

        do        
        {
            printf("New string's position (1 to %d): ", NSTRINGS);
            scanf("%d", &pos);
            getchar(); /* discards '\n' */
        }
        while(pos < 0 || pos > NSTRINGS);

        if (pos == 0){
            i = 0;
            break;
        }
        else{
            printf("New string: ");
            fgets(str, 80, stdin);
            str[strlen(str) - 1] = '\0';
            v[pos - 1] = realloc(v[pos - 1], strlen(str)+1);
            strcpy(v[pos - 1], str);
        }
    }
    free(v);
    v = NULL;
    return 0;
}
```

The sole objective is to allocate 3 strings in accordance to the space necessary (as to preserve the unused one). But then, even after using free(v), this is what valgrind returns to me (filling them in order by 1 2 3 and then 0):

```
[...]
==6760== 
==6760== HEAP SUMMARY:
==6760==     in use at exit: 20 bytes in 3 blocks
==6760==   total heap usage: 6 allocs, 3 frees, 2,092 bytes allocated
==6760== 
==6760== 20 bytes in 3 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==6760==    at 0x4C2FA3F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==6760==    by 0x4C31D84: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==6760==    by 0x4009EB: main (in /home/esdeath/Prog/PL2/a.out)
==6760== 
==6760== LEAK SUMMARY:
==6760==    definitely lost: 20 bytes in 3 blocks
==6760==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6760==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6760==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6760==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6760== 
==6760== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==6760== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0
```

And with this, I have two questions I have really been trying to answer, but I am afraid my experience, for now, doesn't really let me:

- First, it states I have 3 allocs even if I never use/reach the realloc function. Does this mean the calloc function is using 3 allocs all alone? And if so, why?
- Secondly, how can I exactly free the 20 bytes (in this scenario)? I am really confused ...

Thanks in advance.

---

**Side note:** I recognize "realloc" may return NULL (in case it fails) and I added that into the program. Unless it was wrongly placed, Valgrind continued to report the same issue, so I ended up removing it (in the undo process) ...

Comment: it's `int main(void)` ... `int main()` is something different. You use `calloc()` incorrectly. It's `calloc(count, size)` not `calloc(size, count)` (should be `calloc(NSTRINGS, sizeof *v)`) and there is no need to cast the result of `*alloc()`. Also please declare/define variables as close to the place where they're used.

Comment: @Swordfish All of those are irrelevant to the question. And the last statement is considered a bad practice in some code bases (like Linux).

Comment: @StaceyGirl That's why it's a comment and not an answer to any question.

Comment: @Swordfish It is still meanigless and advised practices are even somewhat harmful. Do not post crap like that if you have nothing to say.

Comment: @StaceyGirl Whats harmful!? Don't say that sth. is crap without saying *what* exactly is "crap" in your opinion. duh.

Comment: @Swordfish I already mentioned this in the comment above. Declaring variants at the start of the block is usualy practice in C since it was the only way to do this before C99. People who ask for debugging help are not asking for code review. And `main()` could be one (and is) of implementation defined entry points (which C runtime is allowed to have by the standard).

Comment: What ecactly is the input you made for above output from valgrind? Also, it isn't sufficient to call `free(v)`, you also have to free `v[0]` ... `v[NSTRINGS - 1`. before you `free(v)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not `free`ing the memory allocated by `realloc`. Add

```
for (int i = 0; i < NSTRINGS; ++i)
    free(v[i]);
```

before

```
free(v);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it helped. Could you just help me out on something. Why does it list 6 allocs (if I do: 1 2 3 -> 0) instead of just 4? (calloc + 3x realloc)? I am confused with it.

Comment: Depends on your in data. Remember, `realloc` might not need to move your data if you request for a new string that is shorter, or the new one fits in the possible excessive area that it allocated the time before.

Comment: Hmm, just ran it with input (0) and you see 3 frees and 3 mallocs. My guess that your program for such a run is only 1 free and 1 malloc. The rest is the implementation under the hood that needs its own set of 2 free's and 2 malloc's. Call it the baseline level.